# Can Google Maps Android API display WMS layer?

Tags: wms, google-maps-api, android, arcgis-android

I am currently making an app for my final career project, and I am trying to combine the layer of Google Maps and WMS layer that displays a map from a WMS server, helping me with ArcGis SDK for Android,

The **[MapView object of the ArcGIS API for Android](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/MapView.html)** allows you to add WMS layers (with the object WMSLayer), while **[Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)** does not allow it, and I can't find a way of combining these layers.

Someone could tell me if this is possible?

Comment: The question title seems to be answered in the question. The answer to the question title, as noted in the question is I think "No" ~ https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro tells us that ~ With the Google Maps Android API, you can add maps based on Google Maps data to your application.

Comment: Ok thanks nmtoken, now I know it, i will use only wms layers because i need to show some information that google maps doesn't have,

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to extend google maps API functionality to support WMS Tile Layers. All you have to do is compute the bounding box in EPSG:3857 before and add that as parameter to the request extending google's TileLayer capabilities.

Here is a nice source for doing that: http://www.azavea.com/blogs/labs/2013/01/wms-on-android/

Answer (score 0):

yes you can Implement Using a Google Maps Android API v2, TileLayer please go through with this code it might help you : https://github.com/akshay-shetty/wms_service/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can display WMS layer. Below is the code. You can use this by changing your WMS URL.

```
public static WMSTileProvider getOsgeoWmsTileProvider(String url) {

        //This is configured for:
        // http://beta.sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/maps/services
        // (TODO check that this WMS service still exists at the time you try to run this demo,
         if it doesn't, find another one that supports EPSG:900913
        final String WMS_FORMAT_STRING =                "https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms" +
                "?service=WMS" +
                "&version=1.1.1" +
                "&request=GetMap" +
            "&layers=topp:states" +
                "&bbox=%f,%f,%f,%f" +
                "&width=256" +
                "&height=256" +
                "&srs=EPSG:900913" +  // NB This is important, other SRS's won't work.
                "&format=image/png" +
                "&transparent=true";
        final String WMS_FORMAT_STRING=url;

        WMSTileProvider tileProvider = new WMSTileProvider(500,500) {
            
            @Override
            public synchronized URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {
                double[] bbox = getBoundingBox(x, y, zoom);
                String s = String.format(Locale.US, WMS_FORMAT_STRING, bbox[MINX],
                        bbox[MINY], bbox[MAXX], bbox[MAXY]);
                Log.d("WMSDEMO", s);
                URL url = null;
                try {
                    url = new URL(s);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    throw new AssertionError(e);
                }
                return url;
            }
        };
        return tileProvider;
    }
```